# I need example of code that usins PAPI to copy Page with links from MCSC 2002 to Umbraco

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, papi

I need example in .NET that using PAPI to copy Page with links from MCSC 2002 to Umbraco CMS using Umbraco object model.
Another user of this site already done it (Andy Rose  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678533).
But I do not know how to contact him , so Any other help will be more than appreciated.

Thanx,
Igor.

Answer (score 0):

I use the CMSImport package when transferring content from sites to a new Umbraco install.  Perhaps that can work for you?

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport/